# How do I share data between Python processes where one process target is a class method?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, raspberry-pi4

I am developing a module on a Raspberry Pi where I need to run inferences through a CNN model on images captured from the webcam. Due to the time cost of the network and OpenCV's peculiarities with buffering frames, I would like to use python's multiprocessing module in the following way:

- A class called Camera maintains the cv2.VideoCapture() connection with the webcam and continuously collects images. Upon collecting each image, it should be stored in a way which is accessible by another process.
- The main process should retrieve the most recent frame at an irregular interval (certainly slower than the Camera class can retrieve frames.

Some example code is as follows (with unnecessary components omitted):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import cv2

class Camera():
    def __init__(self):

        self.camera_lock = mp.Lock()
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.last_frame = None #attribute to store last captured frame
        self.frame_count = 0 #count number of frames captured
        self.camera_process = mp.Process(target=self.camera_read)
        self.camera_process.start()
    
    def camera_read(self):
        while True:
            ret, frame = self.cap.read()
            if ret:
                with self.camera_lock:
                    self.frame_count += 1
                    self.last_frame = frame
                print("Cam process says: frame {} stored".format(self.frame_count))
                time.sleep(0.1)

    def retrieve_last_frame(self):
        with self.camera_lock:
            return self.frame_count #Only return count for testing purposes


if __name__ == "__main__":

    def frame_consumer(cam, t):
        for i in range(t):
            n = cam.get_frame_count()
            print("Main says: frame {} fetched".format(n))
            time.sleep(2)


    camera = Camera()
    frame_consumer(camera, 20)
```

So by using the object method `retrieve_last` I am attempting to get the value `frame_count` which is being continuously updated. However, my output shows that while the second process running `camera_read` is grabbing frames and incrementing the counter just fine, my main process prints out frame 0 every time.

What am I misunderstanding about python's multiprocessing that is causing my script to behave in this way?

Comment: You have two entirely independent instances of `Camera`, one in each process.  The ONLY attribute that has any ongoing connection between the processes is `camera_lock`, and that is solely because it is a `multiprocessing` object designed specifically to communicate between processes.  In particular, each instance's `frame_count` is entirely unconnected to the other.  You would need to use something like `multiprocessing.Queue` to actually get the images moved between processes.

Comment: the `time.sleep(0.1)` is a grave mistake. wrong. remove that. bad. very bad. terrible. and so on. -- [mre] please. the opencv stuff (source of your data) is independent of your question, which is on how to wrangle processes and communicate between them. -- jason's description sounds like multiprocessing is the wrong approach and can't be made to work. you should just use multithreading. don't be afraid. don't believe everything people say. multithreading isn't bad. in this instance, you won't run into its limitations. the capture thread spends most of its time waiting for the camera.

Comment: @jasonharper So in the `__init__` of the Camera class, when I create the process and set its target to `camera_read`, that is creating a separate process than when I instantiate Camera in main? I'm having trouble seeing where I have two separate instances of Camera.

Comment: When you created a `Process` with a target of `self.camera_read`, `self` had to be transported to the new process.  This involves importing the defining module if needed, and creating an instance of the class.  (This is basically equivalent to pickling and then unpickling an object - you get back an object that's equal to the original, but it's certainly not the *same* object.)  The two processes fundamentally cannot share the same instance, as they are accessing entirely separate memory.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz So the Pi is on a quadruped platform and I'm trying to get it to follow a ball using a CNN to localize the ball in the image. So I'm worried that using threading is going to result in one thread wasting a bunch of time in the network inference and not give the other thread time to keep the single frame "buffer" updated because of the GIL. Not to mention I'll need another thread to perform the movement commands for the platform.

Comment: @jasonharper I see, thank you for explaining. Would it work then to remove the process creation from `__init__` and instead make the process in `__main__` after instantiating the Camera object, as in `cam_process = mp.Process(target=camera.camera_read)`? Or is there no way around using multiprocessing's build in data sharing structures like Queue or RawArray? Unfortunately, shared_memory is not an option because it requires python 3.8+ and I don't want to upgrade python since there is already a lot of ROS functionality being used for movement and I don't want to risk complicating that.